# Primefaces/Jquery InputMask RTL date issue

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am using primefaces 8 InputMask component
like :

```
<p:inputMask id="date" value="#{maskView.date}" mask="9999/99/99"/>
```

also i tried using jquery mask as :

```
$('.dateInput').mask('9999/99/99');
```

and I use direction RTL to input Arabic date

what I expect is that I will input from right to left meaning i will input day then month then year

but what happens is that the the component always start input from left to right meaning year then month then day

how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm your issue with Primefaces 8.0 because the InputMask Jquery plugin used is very old and does not support RTL properly.

```xml
<p:inputMask id="date" value="#{testView.date}" mask="9999/99/99" dir="rtl"/>
```

But for 9.0 I implemented this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3240 which upgrades the Inputmask JS to a newer library found here: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

In 9.0 I have verified your issue will be fixed!

[image]

Comment: That's a great library. I've added it to BootsFaces inputText a few years ago.